# Create folders from array values in PHP

Tags: php

It's possible to create folders using the values of one array like:

```
$folders = array( "GT-I5500", "GT-I5500B", "GT-I5500L", "GT-I5500M", "GT-I5503" );
```

How can I create Five folders from above array using PHP code?

Comment: I have to admit that it's a pretty good question, but have you tried anything first?

Comment: Here you can explore more about directory/filesystem functions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($folders as $folder)
{
if (!file_exists($folder)) {
    mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks i want put folders in this directory how can put this directory into your code C:\wamp\www\php\folders

Comment: change ` mkdir($folder, 0777, true);` to this  `mkrdir('C:\wamp\www\php\folders\'.$folder, 0777, true);` and it will probably work ... I am not a windows person.

Comment: Thanks work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Try this one with the simple [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function :

```
$folders = array( "GT-I5500", "GT-I5500B", "GT-I5500L", "GT-I5500M", "GT-I5503" );
foreach($folders as $folder) {
    $yourDirectory = "C:\\wamp\\www\php\\folders\\".$folder;
    if(! is_file($yourDirectory)) {
        mkdir($yourDirectory);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks how i can this directory within your code C:\wamp\www\php\folders

Comment: By replacing `/path/to/directory/` with `C:\\wamp\\www\\php\\folders`

Comment: Thanks it is work